# How to reference an element in a loop

Tags: python, loops, variables

```
goods = ['beef', 'eggs']

for good in goods:
    output_good = food_consumption[food_consumption['food_category'] == good]
    print(good)
```

This works but instead of the variable output_good being re-written with each loop, I was wondering if there's a way to create output_beef and output_eggs which stores the value permanently in Python?

Comment: You need to add a language tag to this question.  Is it Python, perhaps?

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing that out! I edited the post to include Python! It was common to be able to reference variables using the ' symbol in loops for Stata but I haven't been able to find a similar method for Python yet!